# как реализовать поиск ip c выводом результата

Tags: javascript, json

Как с помощью этого сайта http://ip-api.com/ сделать чтобы при вводе ip он отправлялся на сайт и назад возвращались данные с результатом также как и на сайте? Помогите,уже обыскал все,не знаю как сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в [документации](http://ip-api.com/docs/) не описано? Например http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json#examples

Comment: Если конечно вы из тех, кто принципиально не читает документацию - посмотрите куда и какой запрос отправляет сайт, когда вы выполняете поиск. А потом имитируйте такой же запрос

Comment: я не очень силен в этой теме вообще. мне просто нужно,что бы когда я в обычный импут вводил какой-то ip - оно отправляло его на сайт и возвращался мне ответ со всеми данными как на том же сайте.

Answer (score 0):

В devtools можно увидеть запрос в json-API.

```js
let ip = '31.128.85.214';

fetch(`http://ip-api.com/json/${ip}?fields=520191&lang=en`)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(res => console.log(res));
```

*Сниппет может не работать, потому что текущая страница(ruSO) - https, а у этого сервиса нет https-endpoint*